# How to re-enable deleted virtual host manager on Tomcat 7?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

For reasons beyond understanding, I decided to un-deploy the virtual host manager application on my Tomcat 7 installation :-(     I used the application manager gui to do this.  I think that the original files might still be there.

I have a lot of "stuff" running on Tomcat, so would be loath to re-install a fresh copy of Tomcat.  How can I re-enable the un-deployed host manager?

Comment: Deleted or undeployed? The `manager` application doesn't have any "delete" options.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz Good catch.  Edited.  I un-deployed it actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only un-deployed the `host-manager`, then you ought to be able to re-deploy it using the same `manager` application. Tomcat comes with the host-manager application inside of the Tomcat distribution in the `webapps` directory.

If you *aren't* running a split Tomcat deployment (using `CATALINA_HOME` and `CATALINA_BASE`), then you have likely removed the host-manager entirely and will need to recover it from a fresh Tomcat distribution. (And if you don't have any idea what `CATALINA_HOME` and `CATALINA_BASE` are, then you are most likely *not* running a split configuration).

The good news is that you should be able to recover using these steps:

1. Go re-download the exact same version of Tomcat that you are currently running (use the ZIP/tarball version even if you are on Windows and usually use the installer)
2. Unpack the archive into a temporary directory
3. Copy the `host-manager` directory from within the recovery Tomcat's `webapps/` directory into your *real* Tomcat's `webapps/` directory
4. If you have Tomcat configured to auto-deploy, then it will simply auto-deploy and you'll be back up and running